# Creating common between gradle and maven

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I have two projects. One is a Gradle project (Android app actually) and the other is a Maven project (A spring mvc HTTP Server based on TomCat).

These two projects have some objects that they share (The response object for example).

I would like to create a common project that will hold all the objects that the Gradle and Maven projects need.

**What have I tried?**

Well, I know building a project in Maven will add its artifacts to .m2 local repository, which can at least be shared by 2 Maven local projects. But I don't know as much about Gradle and how to share artifacts with it.

I would appreciate any advice you can give me to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'd like to understand Gradle better, a good exercise might be convert the Maven project to Gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can import artifacts from maven repositories to Gradle projects without any problem, for example this artifact from maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Can be included in your grade project as well:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

Follow [this link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-io%7C1.3.2%7Cjar) to see different build system import formats for the above example library.

[Here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/mavenlocal-how-does-gradle-resolve-the-directory-of-the-local-maven-repository/4407) it is explained how to add your local maven repository to the resolution path.

So, by utilizing any maven repository (local or remote) you can deploy and include the same artifact in any of your projects and modules, maven and gradle - based.

Comment: Hi invariant thanks for your reply! Ok so I understand it shouldn't be a problem to do it locally on my machine, but what about other developers that work with the Gradle project on their machine. Seems to me all the classes in the common (local) repository that I have created would not be available for them. What is the best practice is such a case? To create a remote maven repository? Can this be done relatively easily? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, remote maven repository is exactly what you need. There are services like [bintray](https://bintray.com/) that host maven repos, you can also use [git as a secure maven repository](http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/?utm_source=Android+Weekly&utm_campaign=2a657cc8e1-Android_Weekly_218&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-2a657cc8e1-338052073). Basically any remote storage can be used as a maven repository. Then you just need to upload stuff and change the resolution path to point to your remote - that's all.

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thanks a lot!